# When sculpting, my brush changes from Add to Subtract and viceversa

Tags: sculpting

When sculpting, my brush changes from Add to subtract and viceversa if i sculpt in some places of my mesh. How like that?

[image]

As it seen in the image, it switches or changes to add or subtract in some places, so everytime i have to press ctrl and stop pressing it because this thing. In some places flattens, in others just add, and it's absolutely annoying, can't sculpt in peace.

Maybe i pressed some "autocontrol-switch option" somewhere, or maybe not.

What's happening?

Comment: Check your normals: if inverted the sculpt tool will invert his function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to enter *Sculpt Mode* with your model, you can see the warning message *Object has non-uniform scale, sculpting may be inpredictable* .

[image]

1. First, select the object in *Object Mode* and then **Apply the Scale** by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*.
2. Then go into *Edit Mode*, select all by <kbd>A</kbd> and **Make Normals Consistent** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.
3. If normals are now inverted, invert them back by <kbd>W</kbd> > *Flip Normals*.

Then your sculpting tool should work equally on the whole model.

Comment: It says to re-load start up file :L, and f you mean with Edit Mode, i tried it, didn't work.

Comment: Or you can try to Apply the Scale. If that doesn't help, can you attach your .blend via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? Or just a part that has these issues.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4010" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4010/)

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer - I tested it on your model and it should solve your problem.

Comment: I am glad to help you! Enjoy Blending :)